# How to provide libstdc library?

Tags: c++

I have created c++ application in Ubuntu linux and now trying to run it on Centos linux. Got error:

```
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found
```

How usually is performed in this situation? Can I somehow put all libs to my executable? Should I install them like:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

Is it normal this libruary is not not installed in standard fresh linux installation?

Comment: How to provide the required library *on Centos* is really off topic here - but see for example [GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not found on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205687/glibcxx-3-4-21-not-found-on-centos-7). Yes you can *"somehow put all libs to my executable"*, by linking your application statically - see [C++ application - should I use static or dynamic linking for the libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095363/c-application-should-i-use-static-or-dynamic-linking-for-the-libraries)

Answer (score 1):

To compile C++ on a freshly installed ubuntu system one would need the package 'build-essential'.

$sudo apt install build-essential